# How to Use Selenium Webdriver to download files via a list of URLs

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a code that use Selenium Webdriver to download files via a list of URLs but for some reason it didn't download anything to my assignedn directory. The code works perfectly fine when I only download it one by one but when I use a for loop, it doesn't work.

This is an example URL: https://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?documentId=WHD-2020-0007-1730&attachmentNumber=1&contentType=pdf

Here is my code:

```
download_dir = '/Users/datawizard/files/'

for web in down_link:
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('headless')
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
          "download.default_directory": '/Users/clinton/GRA_2021/scraping_project/pdf/',
          "download.prompt_for_download": False,
          "download.directory_upgrade": True,
#           "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
          "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
        })
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

        driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
        params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
        command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
        
        driver.get(url)
        
    except:
        print(str(web)+"Link cannot be open")
```

I am wondering did I do something wrong with the code since it doesn't give me any error when I ran the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Selenium to download files, you can download files easily using the `request` library

```
import requests

for web in down_link:
    fileName = YOUR_DOWNLOAD_PATH + web.split("=")[1].split("&")[0] + ".pdf" #I created a filename
    
    r = requests.get(web, stream=True)
    with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content():
            f.write(chunk)
```

**Updated Answer based on Selenium**

```
#replace the below value with your urls list
down_link = [
    'https://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?documentId=WHD-2020-0007-1730&attachmentNumber=1&contentType=pdf',
    'https://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?documentId=WHD-2020-0007-1730&attachmentNumber=1&contentType=pdf']
download_dir = "/Users/datawizard/files/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)


for web in down_link:
    driver.get(web)
    time.sleep(5) #wait for the download to end, a better handling it's to check if the file exists

driver.quit()
```

If your files don't have a unique file name - the above code will replace the existing file with the downloaded one.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use that but it gives me an HTTP 500 Error. Only selenium wouldn't throw me this error. I am trying to figure out how to solve that.

Comment: @DataWizard - please review the Selenium based solution, it works fine on my side.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works on my end as well. I am wondering if I want to give each download a unique filename where can I modify it in the code above for the selenium driver.

Comment: being that you don't know the file name, I recommend using a second directory let's say "temp". Everything will be done in the "for" statement after the "sleep"
wait for the file to be downloaded in temp > get the file > rename it > move it in your desired directory

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: It is donwloading the file with the selenium solution but the file does not open :(

Comment: what are you trying to do there?

Comment: to monitor the download progress, just parse the `chrome://downloads` page. see also [How best to test file download links using Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/27342/57619)